# Eclipse: what is the thing next to the scrollbar called?

Tags: eclipse

In the text editing view of Eclipse, there is a vertical bar to the right of the scroll bar. It has little colored markings corresponding to lines of the file with errors/warnings/notes, and you can click the markings (or anywhere on it) to jump to that line. Also when you click a symbol, white or light gray markings light up on the bar corresponding to instances of the symbol in the file.

**What is this vertical bar thing called?**

(I would screenshot it, but it is not working on my system which is why I'm trying to find the name of it, so that I can search for a solution as to why it seems to have disappeared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Window : Preferences : General : Edtors : Text Editors : Annotations" it's called the "overview ruler".

Also in [this javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Fsource%2FSourceViewer.html).

[This bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=82987) indicates that there is a hidden, unsettable, preferences option to turn it off. Might have happened to you.

Comment: Thanks! Now using the term 'overview ruler', a quick Google search revealed the solution. I'm in OS X Lion and the new scrollbar hiding feature was set to show scroll bars "Automatically based on input device". So that explains why the bar was there for me a few days ago, and now isn't: I plugged in my mouse yesterday. Apparently the setting needs to be set to "When scrolling", but when you plug in a mouse it acts like "Always". [Bug report is here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352990).